# Javascript Show/Hide Multiple instances on page - can't change ID

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I have a JS with a Show/Hide element on a page which is written so that end users at my organization can add new content (multiple interviews) without knowing html/js, therefore the ID can't be changed for each instance. If the exiting script can be used with an added var to allow the id number to change (+1) for each instance, that would be ideal, however, a new solution is also welcomed.

```js
function showMoreOrLess(thisObj, bonusContent) {
  var caption = thisObj.innerHTML;
  //alert(caption);
  if (caption == "Read more") {
    document.getElementById(bonusContent).style.display = "inline";
    thisObj.innerHTML = "Read less";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(bonusContent).style.display = "none";
    thisObj.innerHTML = "Read more";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>lots of intro text here</p>
<span id="1" style="display:none">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is ...</p>
    </span>
<p><a onclick="showMoreOrLess(this,'1');">Read more</a></p>
```

Comment: There is no need for `id`'s at all. Just reference the element(s) you need to using relative DOM properties.

Comment: How would the code look if I removed the ID?

Answer (score 0):

If the span you want to hide or show is always right before the paragraph containing the link, you can use DOM navigation properties.

```js
function showMoreOrLess(thisObj) {
  var caption = thisObj.innerHTML;
  var otherObj = thisObj.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
  if (caption == "Read more") {
    otherObj.style.display = "inline";
    thisObj.innerHTML = "Read less";
  } else {
    otherObj.style.display = "none";
    thisObj.innerHTML = "Read more";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>lots of intro text here</p>
<span id style="display:none">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is ...</p>
    </span>
<p><a onclick="showMoreOrLess(this);">Read more</a></p>

<p>Different intro text here</p>
<span style="display:none">
        <p>Blah Blah Blah ...</p>
    </span>
<p><a onclick="showMoreOrLess(this);">Read more</a></p>
```

Comment: What if there are many show/hides on the page?  Would this still work?

Comment: Yes, I showed it with 2, it works the same with any number.